# Retrieving information from Pointer field

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve a field from a `Pointer` as suggested on this [post](https://www.parse.com/questions/javascript-pointers-how-to-retrieve-fields-using-pointers-and-include-in-query) but I'm always getting `undefined`.

This is what my table `Publication` looks like:

- `userId` -> `User`
- `subCategoryId` -> `SubCategory`
- `title`
- `description`

And my `SubCategory` table:

- `categoryId` -> `Category`
- `name`
- `isActive`

And this is my attempt (I only have one row on the table):

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
userQuery.equalTo("objectId", user.id);

var Publication = Parse.Object.extend("Publication");
var publicationQuery = new Parse.Query(Publication);
publicationQuery.include("subCategoryId");
publicationQuery.matchesQuery("userId", userQuery);        
publicationQuery.find({
    success: function(publications) {
        console.log(publications[0].get("title"));
        // This one returns undefined
        console.log(publications[0].get("subCategoryId"));
    }, error: function(error) {
        // Nothing here as suggested by @adolfosrs
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

What I need is:

```
publications[0].get("subCategoryId").get("name");
```

But obviously the latter throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Comment: why are you querying for the user if you already have it?

Comment: @adolfosrs if I don't do that, I get a 400 Bad Request for some reason

Comment: do you have a pointer to user on the Publication class or is it just the objectId string?

Comment: @adolfosrs in my Publication class I have a pointer `userId` to User

Comment: is this cloud code? what is calling this javascript? are you being able to access the `Parse.User.current();` information?

Comment: also, can you edit the question with a screenshot from your publication parse class?

Comment: @adolfosrs I'm pretty new to Parse, I don't know what you mean by cloud code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100427/discussion-between-adolfosrs-and-cesar-bustios).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Pointers in your parse database like the following, there is no need on working with the objectIds.

[image]

The data that you should have is something like this:

Publication:

- user (`Pointer <_User>`)
- subCategory (`Pointer <SubCategory>`)
- title (`String`)
- description (`String`)

SubCategory:

- category (`Pointer <Category>`)
- name (`String`)
- isActive (`boolean`)

So if you are saving the data as expected the following must work:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var Publication = Parse.Object.extend("Publication");
var publicationQuery = new Parse.Query(Publication);
publicationQuery.equalTo("user", currentUser); 
publicationQuery.include("subCategory");       
publicationQuery.find({
    success: function(publications) {
        console.log(publications[0].get("title"));
        // This one returns undefined
        console.log(publications[0].get("subCategory").get("name");
    }
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what my tables look like, but even with your code I'm still getting `undefined` (although the name of the field is really `subCategoryId`)

Comment: add `,error: function(error) { console.log(error) }` right after the success so we can see some logs

Comment: Sadly, nothing on the error log, just the same `undefined` result

Comment: I found it, they created the wrong table for the pointer, `subCategoryId` was pointing to `User` instead of `SubCategory`, I'll just accept your answer and bang my head against the wall

Comment: @CésarBustíos i thought it could be some inconsistency like this. Have a great work ;)